# d3.scale.linear() returns NaN

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to read a json file with `d3.js` where the graphic y axis depends on the maximum number in the json file. When logging the data inside the file I get `30` and `900` which I can use to set my `cy` but when I put it in `yscale()` function, it says the data is `NaN`

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,d3.max(charts)])
    .range([0,height])

var height = 600,
width = 800,
circleWidth = 50,
offSetX = 15

d3.json('_/data.json', function(data){

for (key in data) {
    charts.push(data[key].amount);
};

var graph = d3.select("#graph").append('svg')
.selectAll('circle').data(charts)
.enter().append('circle')
.attr('cx', function(d, i){
    return (i * circleWidth) + offSetX;
})
.attr('cy', function(d){
    return yScale(d);
})
```

Json file

```
[
  {
    "song":"Song1",
    "amount":30
  },
  {
    "song":"Song2",
    "amount":900
  }
]
```

Comment: is height used in range defined ??

Comment: @AhmedEid Yes it is, I've edited my post. Edit: not in the right function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. Should have put the `variables` in the `d3.json` function